# PHP mysqli insert only works once

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli, insert

I've got a script that I needed to change since the data which is going to be inserted into the db got too big to do it at once. So I created a loop, that splits up the array in blocks of 6000 rows and then inserts it.

I don't know exactly if the data is to big for the server to process at once or if it's too big to upload, but atm I got both steps split up in these 6000s blocks.

Code:

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= ceil($alength / 6000); $j++){

    $array = array_slice($arraysource, $j * 6000, 5999);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Ranking (rank, name, score, kd, wins, kills, deaths, shots, time, spree) VALUES ";

    foreach($array as $a=>$value){

        //transforming code for array


        $ra = $array[$a][0];
        $na = str_replace("&#44;", ",", $array[$a][1]);
        $na = str_replace("&#92;", "\\\\", $na);
        $na = str_replace("&#39;", "\'", $na);
        $sc = $array[$a][2];
        $kd = $array[$a][3];
        $wi = $array[$a][4];
        $ki = $array[$a][5];
        $de = $array[$a][6];
        $sh = $array[$a][7];
        $ti = $array[$a][8];
        $sp = $array[$a][9];
        $sql .= "('$ra',' $na ','$sc','$kd','$wi','$ki','$de','$sh','$ti','$sp'),";
    }

    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);
    $conn->query($sql);
}
$conn->close();
```

Right now it only inserts the first 5999 rows, but not more as if it only executed the loop once. No error messages..

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Your logic works as expected for me. Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this'll necessarily help, but what about using [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), and checking [error codes](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) (if any)? Something like this:

```
function create_query(&$value, $key) { 
    //returns query statements; destructive though.
    $value[1] = str_replace("&#44;", ",", $value[1]);
    $value[1] = str_replace("&#92;", "\\\\", $value[1]);
    $value[1] = str_replace("&#39;", "\'", $value[1]);

    $queryvalues = implode("','",$value);
    $value = "INSERT INTO Ranking (rank, name, score, kd, wins, kills, deaths, shots, time, spree) VALUES ('".$queryvalues."');";
}

$array = array_chunk($arraysource, 6000);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    array_walk($value,'create_query');
    if (!$conn->query($value)) {
        printf("Errorcode: %d\n", $conn->errno);
    }
}

$conn->close();
```

Secondly, have you considered using [mysqli::multi_query](http://ttp://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)? It'll do more queries at once, but you'll have to check the max allowed packet size (max_allowed_packet).

Another tip would be to check out the response from the query, which your code doesn't include.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the tips but I figured it out. Didn't think about this ^^

it was the first line after the for loop that i didnt include in my question:

```
array_unshift($array[$a], $a + 1);
```

this adds an additional value infront of each user, the "rank". But the numbers would repeat after one loop finishes and it can't import users with the same rank. 
now it works:

```
array_unshift($array[$a], $a + 1 + $j * 5999);
```